# llvm inliner pass doesn't work

Tags: llvm, inline, llvm-c++-api

I have wrote a wrapper over a function and i want to inline it (this wrapper just maps the arguments for the original function in another way).
I am trying to call the inliner in llvm over my module after my changes and it doesn't do the work, although i tried calling the pass from opt tool and it worked, Any idea what's may be wrong ?

Here is how i call the inliner pass:

```
llvm::PassManager my_passes;
my_passes.add(llvm::createFunctionInliningPass(4096));
my_passes.run(module);
```

Comment: Your code snippet looks fine to me, maybe do some basic sanity checks around it - for example run on a trivial input instead of your regular module, or put a different pass there to see if it works... debugging it might also be a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

I've managed to get the "AlwaysInline" pass working. The steps were much like what you describe:

```
llvm::Module m("MyJIT", llvm::getGlobalContext());
llvm::PassManager pm;
pm.add(llvm::createAlwaysInlinerPass());
...

llvm::Function* f = buildMyFunction();
f->addAttribute(llvm::AttributeSet::FunctionIndex, llvm::Attribute::AlwaysInline);
...

llvm::DebugFlag = true;
pm.runOnModule(m);
m.dump();
```

Note the llvm::DebugFlag variable, which will cause the llvm code generation machinery to spew a healthy amount of diagnostic output. It's declared in `llvm/Support/Debug.h` and can be changed from your code or from gdb via `set llvm::DebugFlag = 1`.

Also try poking around the llvm source; the relevant bits will be in `${llvm_root_dir}/lib/Transforms/IPO/Inliner.cpp`